# Is there a way to override C++ class virtual functions to make them static?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

So I have an abstract class, that I want two classes to derive from. I want DerivedA to implement the same behavior as DerivedB but I want to override the methods in DerivedA such that they apply to all instances, so I want to make them static. Is there a way to do this while keeping DerivedB's functionality unique to each of it's own instances? My end goal is to keep DerivedA static as a lot of the codebase already depends on it being that way. Do I need to implement an interface or will I simply need to redefine two different classes?

```
class AbstractBase
{
    int numPlayers;
public:
    virtual void setNumPlayers(int num) { numPlayers = num };
    virtual int getNumPlayers() { return numPlayers; }
};


class DerivedA : public AbstractBase
{
    int numPlayers;
public:
    static void setNumPlayers(int num) ;
    static int getNumPlayers();
};

// I don't want to have to redefine the functionality here
class DerivedB : public AbstractBase
{
    int numPlayers;
public:
    void setNumPlayers(int num);
    int getNumPlayers();
};
```

Comment: Virtual methods can't be static. For what you are asking, have DerivedA define a separate set of static methods, and then have virtual methods call them as needed.

Comment: A `static` function is not bound to an instance and can be invoked without an instance. Without that instance, how can it know what specific derived class it should be?

Comment: Static functions don't override virtual functions.    Simply override the inherited functions (as the non-static virtuals they are) in `DerivedA` so they call a static member function.   But static and non-static functions in the same class can't have the same signature (combination of name and type of all arguments) so either the inherited function or the static function will need to be given different names.   The static function will (if needed) need to take care of the mechanics of calling non-static member functions or accessing non-static members of each instance of `DerivedA`.

Comment: Once virtual, always virtual. A static function does not belong to the virtual table. Therefore, even If you could override them in C++, how would they be called at the assembly level?

Comment: If you want to avoid code duplication, you can always have non-virtual, protected members in abstract base for that. virtual functions exists so you *can* redefine them.

Comment: Functions already apply to all instances, static or not. Perhaps you want the data members of DerivedA to be static?